# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (Project Euler 14)

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm working on Project Euler problem 14, and I don't get what the problem is. I keep getting a runtime error after the program runs for about 8 seconds–presumably the ArrayLists are getting too large, but how do I avoid this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Problem14 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>listOfLists=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>();

        for (long c=2; c<1000000; c++)
        {
            ArrayList<Long>tempList=new ArrayList<Long>();
            long h=c;
            while (h!=1)
            {
                tempList.add(h);
                if (h%2==0)
                    h/=2;
                else
                    h=((3*h)+1);
            }
            tempList.add(1l);
            listOfLists.add(tempList);
        }

        long maxLength=0;
        long maxPos=0;

        for (int currList=0; currList<listOfLists.size(); currList++)
        {
            long currLength=(listOfLists.get(currList).size());
            if(currLength>maxLength)
            {
                maxLength=currLength;
                maxPos=currList+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The longest sequence is "+maxLength+" numbers
                long. Its position is "+maxPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: hint: chain_len(13) = chain_len(40)+1

Answer (score 4):

You have run the JVM out of available heap memory.  the problem line is

```
ArrayList<Long>tempList=new ArrayList<Long>();
```

This is inside of a loop that runs a million times and is held on to, so you have made a million array lists.  You either need a better data structure or more memory with -Xmx.

In the spirit of the Euler project, you should look for a way to avoid the list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a list of lists.  You don't even need a list.

If you look at your inner list, you add all the values and then all you use is the size().  This means all you really need in the number of times the loop iterated i.e. a counter.  You could store this is a list but..

All you do with the list once all the lengths have been determined is to find the largest.  Instead of storing the lengths in a list you could record just the largest as you go.

This means instead of using a List of List Of Long objects, all you need the largest number of iterations so far and which starting value that was.

Once you have made these changes you can optimise your code quite a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the JVM memory by using -Xmx parameters

Comment: this might work for this particular problem. but his out of memory problem will recur in harder project euler problems.

Comment: @ColinD totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts due to problem definition:

First of all you don't need to save all chains for your number, that means list of lists not  needed at all. You just need to save a number and chain length it produces. Due to max. It is just two integers instead of tons of lists.

By the way you can add caching to save length for already calculated sequences.
for example Map will consist a number and length of chain it produces, that way you rewriting your algorithm that before calculation chain length for one number it check that cache for existing. It saves a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you aren't coding on the command line. If you are then simply using the -Xmx paramters (and then a number) will work... if not you can add arguments like that in eclipse. Right click on your class that you run the project from, go down to "run as" and then "run configurations"

In there you should see and "arguments" tag... add your -Xmx tag there with a number

-Xmx 2048

might work... wish you the best